# Height of QML rectangle depending on child contents (SailfishOS app)

Tags: qt, layout, qml, rectangles, sailfish-os

I have a rectangle which displays some information in the center of my app, like so:

```
   Rectangle {
      id: info
      anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
      anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
      width: parent.width * 0.8
      height: 500

      Column {
         spacing: Theme.paddingLarge

         anchors.top: parent.top
         anchors.topMargin: Theme.paddingLarge
         anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
         anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
         width: parent.width - 2*Theme.paddingLarge

         Row {
            spacing: Theme.paddingLarge * 2
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            Text {
               anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
               font.pointSize: Theme.fontSizeLarge
               text: info.brand
            }

            Image {
               width: 64
               height: 64
               source: "qrc:///graphics/other.png"
               anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
         }

         Text {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            font.pointSize: Theme.fontSizeTiny
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            width: parent.width
            text: info.priceString
         }

         Row {
            spacing: Theme.paddingMedium
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            Rectangle {
               width: 60
               height: 30
            }

            Text {
               anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
               font.pointSize: Theme.fontSizeTiny
               text: info.description
            }

            Image {
               source: "qrc:///graphics/locked.png"
               width: 64
               height: 64
            }
         }

         Row {
            spacing: Theme.paddingMedium
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            Button {
               text: qsTr("Find")
               width: (scooterInfo.width -2*Theme.paddingLarge) / 2 - Theme.paddingMedium
               visible: scooterInfo.mode == "show"
            }
            Button {
               text: qsTr("Missing")
               width: (scooterInfo.width -2*Theme.paddingLarge) / 2 - Theme.paddingMedium
               visible: scooterInfo.mode == "show"
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Now since its a SailfishOS app, the font sizes as well as the padding will differ according to the theme. This leaves me unable to set a fixed height for the `Rectangle`  with id `info`.

It already makes a difference when running in emulator and when running on my device. I can make only one of both fit, not both at the same time.

So I need a way to have the rectangle automatically pick an appropriate height according to its contents, including padding. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `height: childrenRect.height`?

Comment: Yep, gave some weird result.

Comment: I don’t know what a “weird result” means.

Comment: The rect itself disappears/becomes invisible and the rect contents are placed wrong, e.g. no longer centered on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code and got it to work by removing the `top` and `bottom` anchors from your `Column` object. `Columns` will automatically resize themselves based on their children, so you don't need to manually restrict their height.

```
Rectangle {
    id: info
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    width: parent.width * 0.8
    height: childrenRect.height  // Resize to fit children

    Column {
        spacing: Theme.paddingLarge

        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: parent.width - 2*Theme.paddingLarge

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just came to the same solution and was about to comment here :)
Thanks for the hint, it now works fine.